# jqgrid grid grouping not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I try just to group my data by name element, on the example (http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) hide grouping group column is hidden. How to do so?

In the fact on the page there are all 3 columns, but i want to hide group column (name).

by the way main collapse button doesn't work:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/grid.treegrid.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablednd.js"></script>


 var mydata = [
  {elemName : "Temperature 3m", name : "Energy balance station EB1", value : 14 },
  {elemName : "Humidity 3m", name : "Energy balance station EB1", value : 34 },
  {elemName : "Air pressure 0.1m", name : "Energy balance station EB1", value : 540 },
  {elemName : "Server room temperature", name : "Computer infrastructure", value : 28 },
  {elemName : "Free disk space", name : "Computer infrastructure", value : 400 },
  {elemName : "Free disk space", name : "Computer infrastructure", value : 230 },
];

$('#sumGrid').jqGrid({
  data: mydata,
  datatype: 'local',
  height : 'auto',
  rowNum : 30,
  rowList : [2, 5, 10],
  colNames : ["Parameter", "Group", "Value"],
  colModel : [
    {name : 'elemName', index : 'elemName', width : 150, sorttype: 'text', resizable: true},
    {name : 'name', index : 'name', width : 100, editable : true},
    {name : 'value', index : 'value', width: 150, sorttype : 'float', resizable : true, formatter : 'number'}, 
  ],
  pager : '#psumGrid',
  viewrecords : true,
  //sortname : 'name',
  grouping : true,
  groupView : {
    groupField : ['name'],
},
  caption : "Data",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add option groupColumnShow : [false]
to the groupingView like

```
groupingView : { 
 groupField : ['name'],
 groupColumnShow : [false]
 },
```